# Deriving a function from an intergal

Tags: calculus, integration, logarithms

The example given is a physics application but that's not the point. I don't understand what the question has to do with this case of integration. I do know that that's a main use of integration but here he gave $t$ as an integral of $v$. Shouldn't I differentiate both sides relative to $v$ to get $\frac{dt}{dv}$ then use the inverse rule to get $\frac{dv}{dt}$, then integrate relative to $t$?

That's my line of thinking; either have it corrected or his answer explained.

[image]

Comment: You are outlining a valid set of operations, but if you follow them you'll wind up at a dead end where you are no closer to an answer.  The answer to *that* problem is to keep playing around with it until you find a set of operations that *does* arrive at an answer.  Then streamline that answer, and don't show the natural to try ideas that lead to dead ends.

Answer (score 1):

$t = \int \frac 1{20-v} dv$
so you want to differentiate both sides with respect to v.

$\frac {dt}{dv} = \frac {1}{20-v}$

and invert it.

$\frac {dv}{dt} = 20-v$

Giving you a linear diff eq.

$v = C_1 e^{-t} + 20$

$v(0) = 0$

$v = (-20) e^{-t} + 20$

that will work, just as well.

Comment: whats C1e^(-t) ?

Comment: It is the homogeneous solution to a linear differential equation.  If $y' = a y$ then $y = Ce^{at}$